# Proper handling of dependencies under Version Control in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.
I've put my project under Git, hosted it on GitHub.

I'm having trouble handling module dependencies across repositories.

When configuring paths to specific JARs, these paths vary across platforms. For example, on my Windows 7 machine, they are stored in `D:\Lib`, while on my Windows 10 machine, they are found at `C:\IdeaDependencies`.

The problem is that if I choose to syncronize the module IML file, the paths will be the same on each platform, which won't let the IDE find them.

How can I cope with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a simple solution, store your dependencies with your project files, just like any other resource.

You could create an [excluded](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/content-root.html#root_types) folder named `lib` under your module's content root, and use it to store your libraries. This way, their paths will be relative to your project folder (e.g. `file://$PROJECT_DIR$/lib/gson-2.6.2.jar`), and you won't have to adjust them for each platform.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dependencies as submodules inside your project and in this way you don't care where they are located on the disk.

> ***`Submodules`*** ***allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated subdirectory*** of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

---

## ***`git submodule`***

Break your big project to sub projects as you did so far.
Now add each sub project to you main project using:

```
git submodule add <url>
```

Once the project is added to your repo you have to init and update it.

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

As of **Git 1.8.2** new option `--remote` was added:

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

which will ***`fetch`*** the latest changes from upstream in each submodule, ***`merge them in`***, and ***`check out`*** the latest revision of the submodule.

As [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) describe it:

> ***`--remote`***
>
> This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch.

This is equivalent to running `git pull` in each submodule.

---

> ***However, how would I push a commit in the scenario of bug fix in C which affects the code shared with the parent layers?***

Again: using submodule will place your code inside your main project as part of its content. The difference between having it locally inside the folder or having it as part of a submodule is that in submodule the content is managed (commited) to a different standalone repository.

---

This is an illustration of submodule - project inside another project in which each project is a standalone project:

[image]

---

## ***`git subtree`***

***It allows you to insert any repository as a sub-directory of another one.***

Very similar to `submodule` but the main difference is where your code is managed. In submodules the content is placed inside a separate repo and is managed there which allows you to clone it to many other repos as well.

***`subtree`*** is managing the content as part of the root project and not in a separate project.

Instead of writing down how to set it up and to understand how to use it you can simply read [this excellent post](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/) which will explain it all.